# How to get the current item

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am using Boris Moore jsRender http://www.borismoore.com/ and I am trying to get the instance of each item. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
//render
$("divName").html(
    $('#templateName').render('data')
);

//get instance. Here is my problem
$(".PriceFromPerHotel").each(function () {
                selectedItem = $.tmplItem(this);
});
```

By the use of

```
selectedItem = $.tmplItem(this);
```

I am getting the error message

```
Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'tmplItem'
```

---

**EDIT**

the no method exception solved by adding the jQuery template library. The problem now is that I am getting an empty object. It doesn't return the instance.

Here is my html code

```
<script id="templateName" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="resultsBox">
        //lot of code has here
        <p class="offerSiloPrice">{{:Currency}} <span class="PriceFromPerHotel"></span></p>                 
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: try `selectedItem = $.tmplItem($(this));` or `selectedItem  = $(this).tmplItem();`

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed. I am getting the error for both ways [Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'tmplItem']

Comment: you sould [download the plugins](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) and call it inside your page

Comment: I thought that jquery.tmpl was in the same script file with jsRender. That did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmplItem() is jQuery templates syntax. In JsRender the equivalent is $.view(). There are several examples here http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/index.html. You should use either JsRender OR jQuery templates. They have different template tags and different APIs.

In JsRender, things are factored differently than in jQuery templates. jQuery templates have a DOM dependency and provide the $.tmplItem() feature. JsRender has no DOM dependency, and does 'pure string-based rendering', which makes if a lot faster for scenarios where you don't need data linking, and you don't need the $.tmplItem() feature of getting from a DOM element to the rendered template it came from.

But if you do want those features, then you include JsViews in your page, - which is a layer on top of JsRender, and provides the equivalent DOM related features of jQuery Templates, and more...

In JsViews, the tmplItem is called a 'View'.

```
$(selectorOrElement).tmplItem()
```

in jQuery templates corresponds to

```
$(selectorOrElement).view()
```

in JsViews.