# How can I load data from jsrender template and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender, jsviews

I'm working on migrating Jquery template with JSRender library. I need to retrieve data object from the template page and after that I need to update corresponding property. My old jquery.tmpl code is given below:

*JavaScript*

```
function updateItem(event) {
  var $tmplItem = $(this).tmplItem();
  $tmplItem.data.showItem = !$tmplItem.data.showItem;
  $tmplItem.update();
}
```

*html*

```
{{if showItem}}
 <div>
  This is your item.
 </div>
{{else}}
 <div>
  No item.
 </div>
{{/if}}
```

How can I convert this code into jsRender. I did the following:

*JavaScript*

```
function updateItem(event) {
  var $tmplItem = $(this).view().ctx.root[0];
  $tmplItem.showItem = !$tmplItem.showItem;
  //$tmplItem.update();
}
```

`$(this).view()` method from JSviews will helps to retrieve the data from the template. But it is not the exact result which I got from `$(this).tmplItem()`. But there is no `update()` method. Is there any solution to rebind the updated showItem property to template?
I tried some steps from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9780530/9338568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic data binding provided by JsViews, but to do so you need to load the template with JsViews:

```
$.templates("#pageTmpl").link("#page", data, helpers); // Render and link the template
```

Next, when you modify data values, and you want to trigger updated content binding to the new values, you cannot just write:

```
$tmplItem.data.showItem = !$tmplItem.data.showItem;
```

since that will not  raise any event to trigger re-binding. Instead, make an observable change, like [this](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsobservable):

```
$.observable($tmplItem).setProperty("showItem", !$tmplItem.showItem);
```

And now for any tags which you want to bind dynamically to data, use the 'data-linked' syntax: `{^{...`:

In your sample, `{{if showItem}}`, will be re-written as:

```
{^{if showItem}}
```

You can see all that illustrated in this sample code, based on your content:

https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/ctzL3xeg/2/

(The sample also shows an [alternative approach](https://www.jsviews.com/#link-events@datalink-on) to binding events: `<button data-link="{on ~updateItem}">Click me JsV</button>`)

See [JsViews QuickStart](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsv-quickstart) for more information.